# How to define a function that calls two commands where the first one requires an arguments

Tags: key-bindings, emms

I use emms to play music in emacs and I have this function to add a music directory and shuffle it.

```
(defun my-emms-command()                                    
  "Run `emms-add-directory' and `emms-shuffle' in sequence."
  (interactive)                                             
  (emms-add-directory)                                      
   (emms-shuffle))

(global-set-key (kbd "s-m a") 'my-emms-command)
```

But calling on this command returns "wrong number of argumets"

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about emms but...
Basically you either hard-code the required argument :

```
(emms-add-directory "foo")
```

or pass it with the wrapping function:

```
(defun my-emms-command(directory)
,,,
(emms-add-directory directory)
,,,
```

Look at the doc of the specific functions you are using to find out what datatype your argument must be.
BTW, in the case of not hard-coding the directory path, you will need to rethink the user call with a keybinding.

Comment: Hard programming did it. That was quite trivial. Thank you

Comment: hard-coding is not the best practice. But if it's what you want to use, I'd recommend having a function name that declares clearly that it is hard-coded, something like `emms-foo-shuffle`